# Dynamic mysql pivot table failing

Tags: mysql, sql, string, pivot, dynamic-pivot

```
CREATE TABLE `tUSER` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `first_names` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX( `id_number`, `first_names`, `last_name`)
)

CREATE TABLE `tPROFILE` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tUSER_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tTYPES_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`tUSER_id`,`tTYPES_id`),
  INDEX( `tUSER_id`, `tTYPES_id`, `value`)
)

CREATE TABLE `tTYPES` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT( `type`, `description`)
)
```

Above is the schema is need to get a pivot table from when i'm given and ID number or a cellphone number (`Cellphone` is a record in the `tTYPES` table)

My static pivot works because i have populated the table and know the types

```
select tUSER.*,
  max(CASE WHEN tTYPES.type = 'msisdn' THEN tPROFILE.value ElSE 0 END) AS 'msisdn',
  max(CASE WHEN tTYPES.type = 'network' THEN tPROFILE.value ELSE 0 END) AS 'network',
  max(CASE WHEN tTYPES.type = 'points' THEN tPROFILE.value ELSE 0 END) AS 'points',
  max(CASE WHEN tTYPES.type = 'card number' THEN tPROFILE.value ELSE 0 END) AS 'card number',
  max(CASE WHEN tTYPES.type = 'gender' THEN tPROFILE.value ELSE 0 END) AS 'gender'
 from e1m_test.tUSER 
inner join e1m_test.tPROFILE on tPROFILE.tUSER_id = tUSER.id
inner join e1m_test.tTYPES on tPROFILE.tTYPES_id = tTYPES.id
where tUSER.id = 312
```

I need a dynamic pivot query because i wont always know the types
Below is my current effort but it tells me of a syntax error that I'm not able to solve

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
    CONCAT('max(CASE WHEN tTYPES.type="', 
    tTYPES.type, '" THEN tPROFILE.value ELSE 0 END) AS '
    , tTYPES.type))
INTO @sql
FROM
  tTYPES, tPROFILE;

SET @sql = CONCAT('select tUSER.*, ', @sql, ' 
    from tUSER 
    left join tPROFILE on tPROFILE.tUSER_id = tUSER.id
    left join tTYPES on tPROFILE.tTYPES_id = tTYPES.id
    where tUSER.id = 312');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The error

```
09:54:06    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'number,max(CASE WHEN tTYPES.type="gender" THEN tPROFILE.value ELSE 0 END) AS gen' at line 1  0.141 sec
```

Any help or direction would be welcomed

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Simply perform `SELECT @sql;` instead of PREPARE and look at the code. I think that the commas between columns are lost.

Comment: *"but it tells me of a syntax error that I'm not able to solve"*. It might be a good idea to share that error message with us... A side note: why do you include "FROM ... tPROFILE" in your first select? You don't seem to be using any row from that table (but unless empty, probably won't cause your (unknown) error, so just a side note to speed it up).

Comment: @Solarflare I'm adding tPROFILE because value is linked via Foreign key to tTYPES_id
I've also added the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, there are types in `tTYPE` that conflict with MySQL keywords (`number`, for example, is a language keyword). You would need to quote these identifiers, using backticks.

Further suggestions:

- I don't see why you would need table `tPROFILE` in the query that generates the conditional expressions; accordignly, `distinct` seems unnecessary in `group_concat()`
- I would recommend using single quotes for string literals rather than double quotes - although this is allowed in MySQL, it deviates from ANSI SQL standard, for no value added (you just need to properly escape the embedded single quotes)
- there is no need to `concat()` within `group_concat()`; the aggregate functions happily accepts a list of arguments, and seemlessly concatenates them

So:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 
    'MAX(CASE WHEN tTYPES.type=''', tTYPES.type, 
    ''' THEN tPROFILE.value ELSE 0 END) AS `', tTYPES.type, '`'
) INTO @sql
FROM tTYPES;

SET @sql = CONCAT('select tUSER.*, ', @sql, ' 
    from tUSER 
    left join tPROFILE on tPROFILE.tUSER_id = tUSER.id
    left join tTYPES on tPROFILE.tTYPES_id = tTYPES.id
    where tUSER.id = 312'
);

-- debug your query before running it!
-- SELECT @sql;           
           
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions and the correct answer!
The debug command is very helpful!